# $\text{SU}(1,1)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|\lt 1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

Let $\text{SU}(1,1)=\left\{\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right)\mid \alpha,\beta\in \mathbb C,|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1\right\}$. I need to prove that $\text{SU}(1,1)$ acts transitively on $\mathbb D=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|\lt 1\}.$

First I defined a map $\text{SU}(1,1)\times \mathbb D\to \mathbb D$ such that $\biggr(\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right), z\biggr)\mapsto\dfrac{\alpha z+\beta}{\overline\beta z+\overline\alpha}$, which I hope is the required group action.

Let $w=\dfrac{\alpha z+\beta}{\overline\beta z+\overline\alpha}$. Then $z=\dfrac{\overline\alpha w-\beta}{\alpha -\overline\beta w}$. Since $|z|\lt 1$, we have $\left|\dfrac{\overline\alpha w-\beta}{\alpha -\overline\beta w}\right|\lt 1$. It follows that $|w|\lt 1$, that is, $w\in \mathbb D$. So the map is well-defined. Also it is easy to verify that the given map is indeed a group action.

Now to prove the transitivity, my idea is to show that $0$ can be sent to any element in $\mathbb D$. $$\left( \begin{array}{ccc}\alpha & \beta \\\overline\beta & \overline\alpha \end{array} \right)\cdot 0=z\iff \frac{\beta}{\overline\alpha}=z\iff \beta=\overline\alpha z.$$ Since we require $|\alpha|^2-|\beta|^2=1$, we have $|\alpha|^2=\dfrac1{1-|z|^2}$. So $\alpha=\dfrac{e^{i\theta}}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}$ and $\beta=\dfrac{ze^{-i\theta}}{\sqrt{1-|z|^2}}$. Hence the action is transitive.

I think my proof also shows that the action of $\text{SU}(1,1)$ on $\overline{\mathbb D}=\{z\in\mathbb C\mid |z|\leq 1\}$ is not transitive as $0$ cannot be sent to ,say $i$.

Are my arguments correct?

Suggestions/other solutions are welcome.

Comment: Yes your arguments are correct. Strictly speaking: you only computed what are the only possible values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ for an element of $SU(1, 1)$ that maps $0$ to $z$ but, once you had them, did not verify that using this $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you get an element that indeed DOES map $0$ to $z$. I don't see how it could fail, but math is full of surprises so the argument would be stronger if you included this explicit verification.

Comment: (Even more strictly speaking you could even leave out the computation of $\alpha$ and $\beta$, conjure them up from thin air and then verify that they do the job, but this would turn the thing into one of those annoying black magic proofs so I don't recommend this. But I bring it up as a different way of making my previous point, namely that the order of the implications is important.)

Comment: @Vincent Thank you for your suggestions!!