# How to calculate the group action $ SU (1,1) $ on $ SU (1,1) / U (1) $

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras, group-actions, group-homomorphism

How to calculate the group action $ SU (1,1) $ on $ SU (1,1)/U(1) $?

Where $ SU (1,1)/U(1) $ is group quotient.

I know that the general form of a matrix in SU(1,1) is given by

$(\begin{array}{ccc}
\alpha & \beta \\
\beta^* & \alpha^* \end{array})$, where $|\alpha|^2 - |\beta|^2 = 1$

Can you suggest articles? or help me solve it?

Please.

Comment: A problem that becomes easier by generalising. I can suggest Wikipedia: "In every group $G$ with subgroup $H$, left multiplication is an action of $G$ on the set of cosets $G/H$". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action_(mathematics)#Examples

Comment: It depends on the meaning of "calculate".  I suggest you find a natural identification of $SU(1,1)/U(1)$ with the unit disk and then think about its linear-fractional transformations. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3242599/textsu1-1-acts-transitively-on-mathbb-d-z-in-mathbb-c-mid-z-lt-1?rq=1